# Using a `times` block with local variables has strange behavior

Tags: ruby, block

I tried to put together a method to repeat a word or phrase `t` times.  I found a much better way but still aren't sure why this one behaved like it did.

```
# repeats the word s t times for a default of 2
def repeat s, t = 2
    say = s
    t -= 1
    t.times { say << ' ' + s }
    say
end

repeat('hi', 1) # => 'hi'
repeat('hi', 2) # => 'hi hi'
repeat('hi', 3) # => 'hi hi hi hi' [4x]
repeat('hi', 4) # => 'hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi' [8x]
repeat('hi', 5) # => 'hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi' [16x]
```

Inside the `times` block, it seems that `s` is being set to the same thing as `say` after each iteration. Why does this behavior occur?

Comment: Since string provides [`*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-2A), your entire method can be replaced with `s * t`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall A little trickier with the spaces: `(s + ' ') * t`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Ahhhhh I glossed over that. And really you'd also have to `chomp` that to get rid of the extra space on the end. So `((s + ' ') * t).chomp`—still way shorter and significantly more performant than the OP’s original.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Right, and I neglected the final space

Comment: Another alternative would be `([s]*t).join(' ')`, no need for chomping then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the assignment `say = s`, Ruby isn't assigning the value of `s` to `say` but rather the reference (the memory location) of `s`. That is, `s` and `say` point to the same string in memory. Then, in the line `say << ' ' + s`, Ruby first creates a new string with the value of the concatenation `' ' + s`, then appends this to the string pointed to by `say`. Because `say` and `s` point to the same string, `s` is also changed.

It's basically the same as if you just replaced all `s` with `say`.

See the answer from @AJcodez for alternatives to get it to do what you're going for.

Comment: Might be useful to provide a way to not cause the method to have a side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the shovel operator `<<` for strings appends the content to the string itself, and when you assign `say = s`, as @iamnotmaynard pointed out you're assigning the reference.

To better illustrate, the following modifications make `repeat` do what you intended:

```
say = s.dup   # make an actual copy
```

Or you can use `+=` instead of `<<` to build a new string each time (that doesn't point to `s`)

```
t.times { say += ' ' + s }
```

Comment: Note that the latter method (using `+=`) is significantly slower for large values of `t`.

Comment: You scooped me on the alternatives.

Comment: This is a great answer too, I appreciate it.  I need to be more careful with my references.